# How can you tell whether a craft has ammunition?

Tags: ufo-alien-invasion

In UFO: Enemy Unknown, it was easy to see how much ammunition a craft had loaded, as well as the maximum craft payload. Crafts also had to spend time reloading their ammunition when they finished refueling.

In the open-source fan sequel UFO: Alien Invasion, I haven't noticed the craft loading ammunition, and I can't find anything that says how much ammunition a craft is carrying.

Not knowing how much the interceptor can carry makes me a bit nervous: it's hard to tell how much ammunition is being used per engagement (and therefore how much I should be ordering to replace it), since I don't see "4/7 missiles" remaining after shooting something down.

Is there a way to see the craft's ammunition level that I'm missing? How much can they hold (or do they fire ammunition straight from the base's storage)? How fast does the ammunition get used up?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to look at the buying  page - from there you can see your complete ammo inventory at once.